# Libreria JSCH para conexion a servidor SFTP "Preserve Timestamp"

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch

mi pregunta es, si abra alguna manera de configurar JSCH para que no conserve el "Timestamp" al momento de subir los archivos, es decir: en WinSCP viene una opción así:
 [image: Ventana de opciones de WinSCP]

Esa es la opción que quiero configurar en JSCH.
Tengo una parte donde se añade una configuración mediante java.util.Properties, pero no se como añadir esa opción.

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(config);
```

Comment: JSch no mantene fecha.

Comment: Me acabo de percatar de eso, estaba recibiendo un error desde el servidor, y creí que era por eso, puesto que me dio un error parecido en WinSCP pero me dí cuenta que el fallo venia porque intentaba sobreescribir el archivo y en el servidor yo no tengo permisos para sobreescribir. Gracias!